# How does int16_t represent numbers greater than 32767 and not rollover

Tags: c++, types, arduino

This code running on Arduino Uno prints incrementing numbers and wraps around from 32767 to -32768 as expected.

```cpp
int16_t i = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  i++;
  Serial.println(i);
}
```

However this code that one would think is functionally equivalent keeps printing beyond 200000 which no 16-bit number (signed or unsigned) should be able to represent.

```cpp
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  int16_t i = 0;

  while(true) {
    i++;
    Serial.println(i);
  }
}

void loop() {}
```

The Arduino Reference has this note/warning about the `int` data type. Is this related?

> When signed variables are made to exceed their maximum or minimum capacity they overflow. The result of an overflow is unpredictable so this should be avoided. A typical symptom of an overflow is the variable "rolling over" from its maximum capacity to its minimum or vice versa, but this is not always the case. If you want this behavior, use unsigned int.

What is going on in the 2nd code snippet? How is the variable apparently representing this large a number and not rolling over?

Comment: signed overflow is UB...

Comment: The answer is in your quote: "_The result of an overflow is unpredictable so this should be avoided._"

Comment: Probably the best way to figure out consequences of undefined behavior in one or another particular case is to analyze generated assembly code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Incrementing a signed integer beyond its maximum value, i.e. overflowing it, causes the program to have undefined behavior. The effect of this is completely unpredictable. Undefined behavior means that there is no guarantee on how the program will behave. The program could do anything. It doesn't even have to print the earlier numbers as one would expect.

The compiler will compile the program to machine instructions assuming that signed integer overflow does not happen. The instruction it will emit may or may not make sense if there actually is an overflow. It is not something that the compiler will try to make sense of.

The compiler may decide to put `i` in a register, which is likely going to be wider than 16bit, and to use an increment instruction for the native register size. Then it will seem to increment beyond the maximum value because the register can hold larger values.

Or the compiler may decide to use some 16bit add instruction that results in wrap-around when adding beyond the maximum size.

Or the compiler may notice that your loop increments beyond the maximum size and remove the whole loop, because it can't possibly happen in a valid program that you increment beyond the maximum size. Then there will be no output at all.

Or the compiler may notice that your program always increments beyond the maximum size and fail to compile it with an error stating that.

Or the compiler may do anything else that I haven't listed.